# delete version of all packages in a file

Tags: bash, shell, x86, x86-64, gentoo

i have two files packages32.txt - packages64.txt and now i want the diffrence between files so i think delete the versions is better way.

```
sys-libs/libseccomp-2.1.1
sys-libs/libunwind-1.1
sys-libs/libutempter-1.1.6-r1
sys-libs/mtdev-1.1.5
sys-libs/ncurses-6.0-r1
sys-power/upower-0.99.2-r1
sys-process/cronbase-0.3.3
sys-process/htop-1.0.3
sys-process/lsof-4.88-r1
```

I think best idea is delete -version of every line. Is there a way to can handle it on linux? The file has more entry all together was 1500 lines only in 32 txt file.

Thanks for help & Nice Weekend
Silvio

Comment: Are you sure that the program which generated this list, can not generate it in a different format? For example, where the version number is separated by a space from the package name? Your task would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define what difference you want.  Set difference is not commutative.

For example

```
$ comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

will give the set difference `File1 \ File2` (unique entries in File1), whereas

```
$ comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

will be set difference `File2 \ File2`

On a real example:

```
$ comm -23 <(echo -e 'a\nb\nc') <(echo -e 'c\nd\ne')
a
b

$ comm -13 <(echo -e 'a\nb\nc') <(echo -e 'c\nd\ne')
d
e
```

If you want to do the comparison without the version numbers, first you need to trim them.  Based on the sample above it looks like it's `-[0-9]` is the pattern to look.

```
$ f() { sed 's/-[0-9].*//' $1 | sort; }; comm <(f file1) <(f file2)
```

which will give you three columns, unique in file1, unique in file2, common in file1 and file2.  Or, using the options mentioned above you can get diffs only.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer. I want that at end two files there which has only sys-libs/libseccomp sys-libs/libunwind then i can better saw what is installed and what not on the amd64 tree. Gentoo amd64 and x86 has often same software installed only in other version. When version away i can better see what need to install and what not.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff -u <(sed 's/-[0-9].*$//' packages32.txt | sort) <(sed 's/-[0-9].*$//' packages64.txt | sort)
```

`sed` will remove the `-version` part of each file before pipe the result to `sort`. Both results goes to `diff`. The `diff` will show lines only in the first file (`packages32.txt`) starting with `-` and show lines only in the second file (`packages64.txt`) starting with `+`.